# In a rolling hash what is the relationship between the prime used in the division method of the hash function and the base chosen for the numbers?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am self-studying MIT's Introduction to Algorithms. There is a recitation video which goes in depth about the abstract data type Rolling Hash. Here is a link to the Notes for that video (first page is about Rolling Hash): [Recitation 9 Notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/recitation-videos/MIT6_006F11_rec09.pdf)

The example used in the video is of trying to search for a string of size k within a larger string of size n (like searching for a word in a document). A rolling hash can make this task run in O(n).

The idea is that you have a window of size k that starts at the beginning of the larger string. At each step you hash the string in the window and compare it to the hash of the string you are searching for. If the hashes don't match then you haven't found the string you're searching for so you roll the window one character forward and try again.

In order to show why this works, it is necessary to think of the individual string characters as integers of base b (where this base can be anything, but might be the number of possible characters, such as 256 for ASCII). Strings become lists of integers. When you "roll" the search window forward, you use rolling hash operations called "append" and "skip" (or "pop"): you eliminate (skip or pop) the first integer in the list, and append the next integer that is in the document to the list. The video goes in depth about how to go from one window's hash to the next window's hash in O(1), but the hash function used is just the simple modulus function (as can be seen easily in the linked notes above).

There was an audience question, that was answered in a way that I fail to comprehend:

> AUDIENCE: Does p (the prime number used in the modulus function)
>   always have to be less then the base, or can it be anything?
>
> PROFESSOR: It can be bigger than the base. So if I want to not have a
>   lot of false positives, then suppose my base is 256, because that's an
>   extra character. I was arguing earlier that the number of false
>   positives that I have is 1/P basically. So I want p to be as close to
>   the word size as possible. So p will be around 2 to the 4 billion. So
>   definitely bigger. It can work either way. It's better if it's bigger
>   for the algorithm that we're using there.

First of all, if you use prime number p in the modulus function of a simple hash function, then the probability of a collision (assuming simple uniform hashing) is 1/P, correct? What does it mean to say that P should be as close to the word size as possible?

I hope this helps anyone who ever tries to tackle this course in self-study in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really any relation between the two. The base is chosen based on the size of the inputs, and the prime is chosen so that it is big enough to have small chance of a false positive, but small enough to be convenient/fast to perform calculations on.

You do need to make sure that they are coprime (since `p` is a prime, that means that it should not be a factor of the base). This is guaranteed if `p` is larger than the base, so shouldn't really be a problem.

> What does it mean to say that P should be as close to the word size as possible?

The word size is the "natural" size for the architecture on which calculations can be performed quickly. For example, on a 32-bit machine the word size is 32 bits, so you'd often want the hash to be stored in a 32-bit unsigned integer, and use a prime close to 2<sup>32</sup> in value so that the hash values cover most of the possible 32-bit values.